# difficulty getting events to work in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have this code

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin  

class EventDump(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def onLoad(self, edit):
        print "dffdffdfffdfddfff" 
        print view.fileName(), "just got loaded"  

    def onPreSave(self, edit):  
        print self.view.fileName(), "is about to be saved"  

    def onPostSave(self, edit):  
        print self.view.fileName(), "just got saved"  

    def onNew(self, edit):  
        print "dfdfdfdfdfdff"
        print "new file"  

    def onModified(self, edit):  
        print view.fileName(), "modified"  

    def onActivated(self, view):  
        print view.fileName(), "is now the active view"  

    def onClose(self, view):  
        print view.fileName(), "is no more"  

    def onClone(self, view):  
        print view.fileName(), "just got cloned"
```

I got it from this page whose code is a bit out of date- [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples) but I amended it from sublimeplugin to sublime_plugin so it's not out of date, to make it compiles(I mean save and loads!) without error. And I made one or two other adjustments(like "edit" which I see is even more wrong there).  My version loads without error.

But I can't get it to perform..

I want it such that when I do file..new, then text is printed to the console. Thus showing that the event is being triggered. But it isn't doing that.
I want events for when sublime starts and when files are opened.

Ultimately I want to write the filename to a file. But I can't get as far as getting any indication, anything printed to the console, showing that the event has been triggered.

Also if there was some kind of msgbox that'd be great just in case the console isn't in view but that's a side thing that'd help me see events are being triggered

**UPDATE** fine now given Matt's reply-
Based on Matt's reply and the ST2 docs, I have now updated my code so each function is like so. I get no errors loading it, and events are triggered, and it's printing the filename. So, done!

```
def on_post_save(self, view):
    print "done on_post_save"
    print "filename is: "+str(view.file_name())  

def on_new(self, view):  
    print "done on_new"
    print "filename is: "+str(view.file_name())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Sublime Text **2** [API docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html), specifically the section on [`sublime_plugin.EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener). The link you were at referred to the ST1 API. If you're interested in targeting ST3, which uses Python 3.3, just change the `2` in the URL to `3`.

There have been significant changes in the Python API in both ST2 and ST3, although the ST3 changes (at least in my experience) were not as completely disruptive as the 1 -> 2 ones. In your case, the method names have changed to `on_load()`, `on_new()`, `on_pre_save()`, etc.

Finally, make sure you're defining your methods like so:

```
def on_modified(self, view): # <- note change from "edit"  
    print view.fileName(), "modified"
```

`edit` shouldn't be in there, since we're dealing with views here. For more pointers and explanations, the [Plugins](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html) section of the Reference, as well as in [the main docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html) should be helpful. But, I've found the best way to learn is to take apart and analyze other working plugins - [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) is definitely your friend.